# How to get a value from a dict in a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

In this list of dicts:

```
lst = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'qty':'4', 'color': 'green'},
       {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty':'6', 'color': 'orange'},
       {'fruit': 'melon', 'qty':'2', 'color': 'yellow'}]
```

I want to get the value of the `'fruit'` key where the `'color'` key's value is `'yellow'`.

I tried:

```
any(fruits['color'] == 'yellow' for fruits in lst)
```

My colors are unique and when it returns `True` I want to set the value of `fruitChosen` to the selected fruit, which would be `'melon'` in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression:

```
fruit_chosen = next((fruit['fruit'] for fruit in lst if fruit['color'] == 'yellow'), None)
```

This will assign the *first* fruit dictionary to match to `fruit_chosen`, or `None` if there is no match.

Alternatively, if you leave out the default value, `next()` will raise `StopIteration` if no match is found:

```
try:
    fruit_chosen = next(fruit['fruit'] for fruit in lst if fruit['color'] == 'yellow')
except StopIteration:
    # No matching fruit!
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'qty':'4', 'color': 'green'},{'fruit': 'orange', 'qty':'6', 'color': 'orange'},{'fruit': 'melon', 'qty':'2', 'color': 'yellow'}]
>>> next((fruit['fruit'] for fruit in lst if fruit['color'] == 'yellow'), None)
'melon'
>>> next((fruit['fruit'] for fruit in lst if fruit['color'] == 'maroon'), None) is None
True
>>> next(fruit['fruit'] for fruit in lst if fruit['color'] == 'maroon')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: That's great and thanks for showing it in the `try` block to.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension to get a list of all the fruits that are yellow.

```
lst = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'qty':'4', 'color': 'green'},
       {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty':'6', 'color': 'orange'},
       {'fruit': 'melon', 'qty':'2', 'color': 'yellow'}]

>>> [i['fruit'] for i in lst if i['color'] == 'yellow']
['melon']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain that the `'color'` keys will be unique, you can easily build a dictionary mapping `{color: fruit}`:

```
>>> lst = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'qty':'4', 'color': 'green'},
           {'fruit': 'orange', 'qty':'6', 'color': 'orange'},
           {'fruit': 'melon', 'qty':'2', 'color': 'yellow'}]
>>> dct = {f['color']: f['fruit'] for f in lst}
>>> dct
{'orange': 'orange', 'green': 'apple', 'yellow': 'melon'}
```

This allows you to quickly and efficiently assign e.g.

```
fruitChosen = dct['yellow']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `filter` fits better in this context.

```
result = [fruits['fruit'] for fruits in filter(lambda x: x['color'] == 'yellow', lst)]
```

Comment: This produces a list; I disagree `filter()` is better here, not when you *already* need to use a list comprehension to extract the `'fruit'` key.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to each their own. The more I use Python the more a fan I am of the `map` and `filter` functions. That'll probably swing back the other way eventually but it just reads better to me to say "Give me the value in the `fruit` key of all dicts, filtered by those whose color is yellow."

Comment: If you are using `filter()`, then use `map()` too: `from operator import itemgetter`, `map(itemgetter('fruit'), filter(...))`.