# How to get dict value x via dict value y from list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

(Python 2.x) A list of dicts with only unique key-value pairs, sorted alfabetically by name, names are unique as well:

```
dictlist = [
    {'name': 'Monty', 'has': 'eggs'},
    {'name': 'Terry', 'has': 'bacon'}    
    ]
```

I want to get what a given name has, by name. The following works.

```
names = ['Monty', 'Terry']

print dictlist[names.index('Terry')]['has']
```

I've made a parallel list with just names in the same order as the names in the dictlist, so I can make use of the *order* of the list. (I could fill `names` with a `for` loop, but that's not relevant here).

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344934/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-dict-in-a-list-of-dicts), among others, I know I could do this:

```
print next((d['has'] for d in dictlist if d['name'] == 'Terry'), None)
```

but that's only better if dictlist isn't sorted by name.

So I'm wondering if there isn't a more concise way of doing this, preferably one that's at least as readable as the first method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not use a list at all. I would use a dictionary instead.

```
dictlist = {
    'Monty': {'has': 'eggs'},
    'Terry': {'has': 'bacon'}    
    }
```

This allows you to look up values by name like so: `dictlist['Monty']['has']`

If you must use a list then I think you have a good solution as-is.